# 'as compared to' vs 'as compare to'

Tags: as, participles

The sentence below:

> Our method cannot achieve 100 percent accuracy as compared to DART method due to the imprecise modeling.

Why does the sentence above use *as compared to*? Can we use *as compare to* instead?

Comment: probably should be "as compared to the DART method", it needs the article.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "as *compared* to..." is correct. "As *compare* to..." would not be accepted as correct by any English speaker.

Comment: Actually *"as compared to"* and *"as compare to"* sound very similar when spoken. So it might easily be accepted by an English *listener*, but not an English *reader*.

Answer (score 0):

The above sentence is incorrect. `Compared` is not an adjective, it is an ordinary verb, hence the adverb **as** is used mistakenly. The sentence should read:

> Our method cannot achieve 100 percent accuracy **compared to** DART method
>   due to the imprecise modeling.

[**Compare**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compare?s=t) = to examine (two or more objects, ideas, people, etc.) in order to note similarities and differences: to compare two pieces of cloth; to compare the governments of two nations.

(The construction **as** [`adjective`] **as** is common when *comparing* two things or people for example: "Our method is **as** accurate **as** theirs.")

from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compare?s=t):

> The traditional rule about which preposition to use after `compare` 
>   states that compare  should be followed by `to`  when it points out
>   likenesses or similarities between two apparently dissimilar persons
>   or things: "She compared his handwriting to knotted string."

**EDIT:** I must be more careful before making sweeping statements such as "compared" is not an adjective, it is not as clear-cut as that. Kiamlaluno has provided a clear and very comprehensible explanation on ["**compared to**"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7334/1694) and I would like to copy his answer here so that others may benefit.

> "Compared is the past participle of compare and "compared to the DART
>   method due to the imprecise modeling" is a participial phrase.
>   **Participial phrases function as adjectives**; in your sentence, it
>   modifies our method."

kiamlaluno

Comment: Native speakers frequently use "as compared to". They do not, however, use "as compare to". So by any *practical* measure, "as compared to" is correct, and "as compare to" is incorrect. Whether it's better to leave out the "as" or not is a stylistic question, not a grammatical one.

Comment: Thank you @Martha. I will do a little research and post the results, but only tomorrow.

Comment: *Compared* **is** an adjective: it is a participle, a form which is so called because it 'participates' in characteristics of both nouns and verbs.

Comment: Thanks, since it is a different questions from this, I post a related question here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7332/is-compared-to-a-verb

Comment: @StoneyB before claiming that compare is a verb, I checked on two dictionaries: Dictionary.com and Collins, I typed both "compared" and "compared to" and nowhere did either reference book say that compared is or can be used as an adjective. I checked because I was uncertain, and **"compared"** looks like an adjective. So I am now a bit confused, I need more convincing before correcting my answer. Could you provide me with any links? Thank you.

Comment: @StoneyB I also tested my inner ear: "I am more compared than...; He is the most compared in the..." and they didn't sound right. Perhaps my method was too primitive? :(

Comment: @StoneyB [Kimalaluno's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7334/1694) has helped me to understand better. You were indeed correct. I've always avoided the trickier aspects (for me) of English grammar and now I see I am falling flat on my face, so to speak!

Comment: @Mari-LouA We never stop learning. I've spent the last ten months here and on ELU un-learning everything I learned about grammar 50 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "compare". When you use the verb form "compare" it is a finite form of present tense that needs a subject such as a pronoun (I, you ...). It might also be an imperative when it is the first word of a sentence and it might also be a subjunctive form when used in a subclause after special verbs.